# How to catch an event when keyboard Enter key is pressed on UIWebView?

Tags: ios, events, uiwebview, keyboard

How to catch an event when keyboard Enter key is pressed on UIWebView?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any public API that gives you access to the keyboard press event or notification. You must found for another way. of to do this, is to put a transparent button over top the each key, and detect that, and then pass on the touch to the underlying button.

Comment: How to pass on the touch to the underlying button?